# Dockerized Actix server "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: docker, rust, actix-web

I built an API server using Rust and Actix and spent hours trying to Dockerize it. I finally found a Dockerfile configuration which at least builts successfully:

```bash
FROM rust:latest as builder
ENV APP backend
WORKDIR /usr/src/$APP
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path .
 
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl1.1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/$APP /usr/local/bin/$APP

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["backend"]
```

Here is my server code:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "debug");
    std::env::set_var("RUST_BACKTRACE", "1");
    env_logger::init();

    const DB_URL: &str = "postgresql://postgres:mypwd@localhost:5432/mydb";
    let db_pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(5)
        .connect(&DB_URL)
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let app_state = web::Data::new(AppState{ db_pool });

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        let logger = Logger::default();
        App::new()
            .app_data(app_state.clone())
            .wrap(logger)
            .route("/", web::get().to(get_root))
            .route("/openapi", web::get().to(get_openapi_definition))
            .route("/test/{id}/test", web::get().to(get_test))
            .route("/test2", web::get().to(get_test_2))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

This works fine locally but when I run the container using `sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 test-backend` it get the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Os { code: 99, kind: AddrNotAvailable, message: "Cannot assign requested address" })', src/main.rs:36:10
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at ./rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/std/src/panicking.rs:579:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at ./rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/panicking.rs:64:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at ./rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/result.rs:1750:5
   3: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
   4: <core::pin::Pin<P> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
   5: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CurrentThread::block_on
   6: tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on
   7: backend::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

I tried binding using `("0.0.0.0", 8080)` but that also didn't work.

Comment: you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Marty sadly no :/